# AngularJS + Jquery Date PIcker now showing values in view page

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker, momentjs

I'm using an angular Date Picker jQuery and momentJS in my project.  It works when I test it in a static environment, but when I add it to my project the data does not bind.  It pops up but I only see the code not values. I followed instructions from Github. [https://github.com/wstaeblein/ngSimpleDatePick]

This is what my popup looks like
[image]

Here is my directive:

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module('datePicker', []);

var sdp_id = 0;
var isofmt = 'YYYY-MM-DD';

app.directive('simpleDatePick', ['$compile', '$document', function($compile, $document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel',
            chosendate: '=sdpDate',
            ondateselected: '&sdpOnDateSelected',
            sdpMin: '=',
            sdpMax: '='
        },
        compile: function(element, attributes) {

            var uid;
            var html = ' <div class="datepick" id="spd" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" ng-cloak>' +
                        '<div class="datepick_header">' +
                            '<a href ng-click="setMonth($event, -1)"><span class="datepick_arrowleft"></span></a>' +
                            '<span class="titleMonth" >{{ actualDate.format("MMMM") | uppercase }}</span>' +
                            '<a href ng-click="setMonth($event, 1)"><span class="datepick_arrowright"></span></a>' +
                            '<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>' +
                            '<a href ng-click="setYear($event, -1)"><span class="datepick_arrowleft"></span></a>' +
                            '<span class="titleYear">{{ actualDate.format("YYYY") }}</span>' +
                            '<a href ng-click="setYear($event, 1)"><span class="datepick_arrowright"></span></a>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="datepick_body">' +
                            '<table class="datepick_datecontainer" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">' +
                                '<thead>' +
                                    '<tr>' +
                                        '<td ng-repeat="dname in monthObj.weekdays">{{ dname }}</td>' +
                                    '</tr>' +
                                '</thead>' +
                                '<tbody>' +
                                    '<tr ng-repeat="wk in monthObj.dates">' +
                                        '<td ng-repeat="cell in wk" ng-click="setDate($event, cell)" ' +
                                        'ng-class="{ datepick_outdatecell: cell.outofmonth, datepick_disabled: cell.disabled, ' +
                                        'datepick_today: cell.today, datepick_initial: cell.initial }">{{ cell.day }}</td>' +
                                    '</tr>' +
                                '</tbody>' +
                            '</table>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="datepick_footer" ng-show="showFooter">' +
                        '<div><a href ng-click="setDate($event, today)">Today</a></div>' +
                        '<div><a href ng-click="clearDate();" ng-show="model">Clear</a></div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>';


            return function($scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

                ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {

                    var format = attr.sdpFormat || 'YYYY-MM-DD';

                    if (moment(value).isValid() == true) {
                        return moment(value).format(format);
                    } else {
                        return value;
                    }

                });

                sdp_id++;
                uid = "sdp_id" + sdp_id;
                html = html.replace('spd', uid);
                uid = '#' + uid;

                var format = attr.sdpFormat || 'YYYY-MM-DD';

                $scope.showFooter = attr.footer == undefined ? true : (attr.footer != '');
                $scope.today = { disabled: false, date: moment() };


                $scope.actualDate = moment($scope.model || $scope.chosendate, format);
                if ($scope.actualDate.isValid() == false) { $scope.actualDate = moment(); }

                // Compile the html, link it to our scope and append the result to the page's body
                var linkFn = $compile(html);
                var content = linkFn($scope);
                var body = $document.find('body').eq(0);
                body.append(content);

                // Answers the original div or input click event
                element.on('click', function(evt) {

                    // Calculate the dropdown box's position
                    var elePos = $(element).offset();
                    var top = elePos.top + $(element).outerHeight() + 2;
                    var left = elePos.left;
                    $scope.initialDate = moment($scope.model || $scope.chosendate, format);

                    if (top < 0) { top = 0; }
                    if (left < 0) { left = 0; }

                    // Apply the changes in the current month and render the calendar
                    $scope.$apply(function() {
                        $scope.monthObj = renderMonth($scope.actualDate, $scope.sdpMin, $scope.sdpMax, $scope.initialDate, format);

                        $('.datepick:not(' + uid + ')').hide();

                        $(uid).fadeIn(400).css({ 'top': top, 'left': left });
                        evt.preventDefault();
                    })

                    return false;
                });

                // Dismisses the date picker box when the user clicks somewhere else
                $document.on('click', function($event) { goAway(400); });


                $scope.clearDate = function() {

                    $scope.model = '';
                    goAway(400);
                }

                // Answers a year navigation click
                $scope.setYear = function(e, val) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $scope.actualDate.add(val, 'y');
                    $scope.monthObj = renderMonth($scope.actualDate, $scope.sdpMin, $scope.sdpMax, $scope.initialDate, format);
                }

                // Answers a month navigation click
                $scope.setMonth = function(e, val) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $scope.actualDate.add(val, 'M');
                    $scope.monthObj = renderMonth($scope.actualDate, $scope.sdpMin, $scope.sdpMax, $scope.initialDate, format);
                }

                // Answers a date cell click
                $scope.setDate = function(e, cell) {

                    e.stopPropagation();

                    if (!cell.disabled) {

                        $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
                            if ($(element).attr('sdp-date')) {
                                $scope.chosendate = cell.date.format(format);
                            } else {
                                $scope.model = cell.date.format(format);
                            }

                            if ($scope.ondateselected) {

                                $scope.ondateselected({ seldate: cell.date.format(format) });
                            }
                        });
                        goAway(400);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Dismisses the date picker box
            function goAway(speed) {

                $('.datepick').fadeOut(speed);
            }

            // Renders a month of a year passed in dt. 
            // min and max determines which cells can be selected
            // inidate is the date at the box when it was clicked
            // Format is the format in which to show dates
            function renderMonth(dt, min, max, inidate, format) {

                var ini = moment(dt), m = ini.month(), y = ini.year();
                var fim = ini.date(0);
                var counter = ini.add(-ini.weekday(), 'd');

                var dateObj = {};
                var lines = [];
                var wdn = [];
                var tmp = counter.clone();
                var idate = '';
                if (inidate != undefined) { idate = inidate.format(isofmt); }

                for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                    wdn.push(tmp.format('ddd').toUpperCase());
                    tmp.add(1, 'd');
                }

                if (min || max) {

                    var mindate = moment(min + ' 10:00:00', format + ' HH:mm:SS');
                    if (!mindate.isValid()) { mindate = moment(new Date(1970, 1, 1, 10)); }

                    var maxdate = moment(max + ' 10:00:00', format + ' HH:mm:SS');
                    if (!maxdate.isValid()) { maxdate = moment(new Date(2160, 12, 31, 10)); }
                }

                for (var l = 0; l < 6; l++) {

                    var line = [];

                    for (var c = 0; c < 7; c++) {
                        var dis = false;

                        if (min || max) {
                            var adate = counter.format(isofmt);
                            dis = !(adate >= mindate.format(isofmt) && adate <= maxdate.format(isofmt));
                            console.log(adate + ' ==> ' + mindate.format(isofmt));
                        }

                        var ctrfmt = counter.format(isofmt);
                        var obj = { date: counter.clone(),
                            day: counter.date(),
                            outofmonth: (counter.month() != m),
                            disabled: dis,
                            today: (moment().format(isofmt) == ctrfmt),
                            initial: (idate == ctrfmt)
                        };

                        line.push(obj);
                        counter.add(1, 'd');
                    }
                    lines.push(line);
                }

                dateObj.dates = lines;
                dateObj.weekdays = wdn;
                dateObj.month = m;
                dateObj.year = y;

                return dateObj;
            }
        }
    }
} ]);}());
```

Here is my form (view):

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 CellStyleForTheForm">
            <form name="userForm" class="form-inline">

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label >Date Range: </label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="queryparams.min_date"
                        size="12" simple-date-pick />
                    <input type="text"  ng-model="queryparams.max_date"
                        size="12" simple-date-pick />
                </div>

                <button type="submit" 
                    class="btn btn-default"
                    ng-click="queryParams.submitCount = queryParams.submitCount + 1" 
                    ng-init="queryParams.submitCount=0">
                    Apply
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm new to angularjs, please help..  Thanks

Comment: Do you have any errors displaying in your browser console?

Comment: `It works when I test it in a static environment, but when I add it to my project the data does not bind.` There must be some javascript error causing the rest code to stop running

Comment: No errors at all in my browser's console.